# How to make the home screen of my blog not show full posts?

Tags: posts, user-interface

I recently set up my blog and on the home screen, the full blog posts are shown. Is there a way to cut off the blog posts at some point in the text? As it is now, my home screen is extremely long with a bunch of full blog posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is usually dependent upon the theme that you are using. But you can also manually set each blog post to only show so much with the `<!-- more -->` tag that you insert in to each post.

If you're wanting to update the theme template file, you'd replace the_content() function call with the_excerpt() function call (see the Codex for details on how to use) in the template file that is being loaded on your home page which depends upon the theme. Could be front-page.php or archive.php or index.php in your selected theme's directory.

Comment: I am using the TwentyThirteen theme. Would you know how to set that in that theme? Thank you! :)

Comment: Ooo. TwentyThirteen is a beautiful theme, but I don't know it has this as default functionality or as a setting that can be tweaked. Some other themes do have an options panel where can specify an excerpt. For example, I recently worked on a theme for a client that had that as an option, but its my understanding that this isn't the place to promote themes and such. If you wanted extend the twenty thirteen theme, you could do that by creating a child theme which is dependent upon TwentyThirteen, but that may be over your head.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually done by including a `<!--more-->` tag in your post.  You can insert this tag by clicking on the "Insert More Tag" toolbar button as you are editing your post.  The toolbar button looks like this: [image: Insert More Tag]

The portion of your blog post above that tag will be shown on your home screen.  The portion below that tag will be hidden unless the user clicks through using the "Continue Reading" link.